# iPhoneのsafariでtarget=“subwindow”とした時にタブを切り替えたい（手前に表示したい）。

Tags: html

iPhoneのsafariで

```
target="subwindow"
```

としたa要素をタップしたときに、すでにそのページが開かれていると、
タブが切り替わりません。

一回目のタップで
新規タブとして開くときに切り替わるのと同様に、
すでに開いているときにも切り替えて手前に表示したいのですが、どうすればよいですか？
JavaScriptを使わない方法があれば知りたいです。